# Fixed Menu -> media screen css not working

Tags: html, css

i have fixed menu. I will If the browser size is small, Menu get left -130px... because not working?

```
#nav {
    left: -20px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    margin-top:415px;
    z-index:99;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
#nav {
    left: -130px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    margin-top:415px;
    z-index:99;
}
}
```

Comment: you just need to hide the menu?

Comment: because your piece of code working primedenny

Comment: yes and correctly describe your question because it is not clear what you expect the result

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
#nav {
    display:none;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
@media screen and (min-width: 601px){
 #nav {
    left: -20px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    margin-top:415px;
    z-index:99;
 }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
 #nav {
    left: -130px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    margin-top:415px;
    z-index:99;
 }
}
```